# Need to compare values from two lists, where both lists have multiple duplicates [VBA]

Tags: vba, excel

I've searched thoroughly but can't find something applicable to my problem.

I have two lists. The first list ("Reference") contains a list of paired values: a Group and a Member. The second list ("Data") contains unorganized data with many Members and Attributes. I need to compare both lists to combine the Attributes of various Members into their correct Groups.

To make this clearer, here's a pretty good example of what I'm trying to do. Let's say you had a list of kids at a school (Members) and their test scores (Attributes).

Data:

- Alex  | 90
- Bob   | 80
- Carol | 95
- Dina  | 100
- Dina  | 90
- Bob   | 90
- etc

and a list of their Groups.

Reference:

- ALLSTUDENTS | Alex
- ALLSTUDENTS | Bob
- ALLSTUDENTS | Carol
- ALLSTUDENTS | Dina
- MALES       | Alex
- MALES | Bob
- FEMALES | Carol
- FEMALES | Dina
- FRESHMAN | Carol
- FRESHMAN | Bob
- SENIORS | Alex
- SENIORS | Dina
- etc

What I need as my output is a list of Groups and the average scores of the students in that group.

- ALLSTUDENTS | 93
- MALES | 87
- FEMALES | 95
- FRESHMAN | 90
- SENIORS | 92
- etc

I currently have a rudimentary VBA macro that loops through the Reference list (~1500 values), and then for each entry loops through a test Data list. However, this takes almost a minute to run with ~500 values in the Data list, and the real Data list I could have anywhere from 5,000 - 100,000 entries. I'm looking for a faster way to do this. I've seen VBA solutions to the double-loop problem but they rely on exiting the loop when you find a match or using a lookup to find a match. I can't do this because there are a indeterminate number of repeat values in both the Reference and Data lists.

Sorry for the novel. Thanks for any help.

Comment: how about just [`AVERAGEIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIFS-function-48910C45-1FC0-4389-A028-F7C5C3001690) function. No need for VBA. Paired with a [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/VLOOKUP-function-0BBC8083-26FE-4963-8AB8-93A18AD188A1) to get the student to group.

Comment: Is there a way to reference `AVGERAGEIFS` to a list of values? Something like `Males` might have 500 associated values that would need to be averaged. And I can't `Vlookup` because each student is in at least two groups.

Comment: I will post an answer that will be easy to follow.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is outlined like in the below picture, take the following:

- G1 formula: `=VLOOKUP(F1,$A$1:$B$6,2,0)` *copy down rows*
- K1 formula: `=AVERAGEIF($E$1:$E$12,J1,$G$1:$G$12)` *copy down rows*

[image]

**EDIT**

This is another approach to account for multiple test scores per person. You can easily add any more groups as needed and copy formulas.

- C2 formula: `=IF(COUNTIFS($J$2:$J$13,C$1,$K$2:$K$13,$A2)=1,$B2,"-")` *copy across and down*
- P2 formula: `=AVERAGE(OFFSET(B2:B7,0,MATCH(O2,$C$1:$G$1)))` *copy down*

[image]

Comment: Thanks spending time on this. The problem with this solution is that it doesn't take into account students with multiple test scores. For example, Dina has two entries (100 and 90), but the `Vlookup`/`AverageIf` only finds the 100.

Comment: Additionally, I don't know how many Groups there might be or what they may be called. I may get a dataset that has `StudentsWithBlondHair` or some other ridiculous new group!

Comment: @WhatMonster - see my edits